# Writing To a file using fstream will erase the file

Tags: c++, file

I have a problem, I have a saved text file, I want to use `fstream header` file in C++ to write something to that file, but using `ofstream` will erase the whole file as soon as I run the compiled application, why and how to avoid it?

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ofstream write("1.txt");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to tell ofstream to append to the file.

```
std::ofstream write("1.txt",std::ios::app);
```

There are several other flags that control similar characteristics of the stream, read a book or [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/) for more information.